# IIS Url Rewrite ARR issue

Tags: url, redirect, iis, url-rewriting, arr

I configured IIS as a reverse proxy using Url Rewrite module and ARR 3.
I have a public domain which redirect to my application on localhost.
It's working fine excepted when the application redirect to another host.
ie: redirecting to "https://www.google.com/search?q=url+rewrite+iis+arr+3"
My browser shows "http://localhost/search?q=url+rewrite+iis+arr+3"
which fails

The hosted application is using Asp Net Mvc with framework.net 4.5.
The application is working with integrated pipeline in IIS application pool configuration.

Using Fiddler, I can see the following trace on redirect :

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 350
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: http://localhost/search?q=url+rewrite+iis+arr+3
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ARR/3.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 02 Nov 2016 16:39:18 GMT

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=url+rewrite+iis+arr+3">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

My IIS config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="IsRedirection" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match filterByTags="A" pattern="^http(.*)" negate="false" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="IsRedirection">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="3[0-9][0-9]" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to milope on IIS.net forums (don't know if I can post the link) for giving me the following solution:

> In the server level Application Request Routing Cache feature, there
>   is a link that reads: Server Proxy Settings or something like that.
>   Check if the Reverse rewrite host in response header is checked in the
>   Proxy Settings. If so, this may be why external link go to localhost.

This worked for me and solved my redirect issue.