# URL Rewrite, ARR and SSO AzureAD with OWIN OpenIdConnect using wrong URL

Tags: azure, networking, url-rewriting, openid-connect, arr

I am currently using the IIS URL Rewrite Module and Application Request Routing on a server in the DMZ to forward requests to a web application running on an internal server.

The application which is deployed on the internal server has SSO which includes Azure AD using OWIN pipeline and openIdConnect.

When a user selects the authenticate using AzureAD option instead of being redirected to the `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantname>/...`
they are redirect to `http://my.company.com/<tenantname>/...` where `http://my.company.com` is the URL used to access the application from the DMZ.

The SSO works for all internal instances i.e. where request are not being forwarded in a reverse proxy scenario.

Why is this happening when using URL Rewrite and ARR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unchecking the **Reverse rewrite host in response headers** checkbox under **Application Request Routing Cache > Server Proxy Settings** solved this issue.

> **Reverse rewrite host in response headers (checked**)
>
> ARR will rewrite the host name in the location header of a 301
>   response to the original host.

- [URL Rewrite keeps original host Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508938/url-rewrite-keeps-original-host-location-when-reverse-proxy-301-redirects)
- [IIS Url Rewrite ARR issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40385575/iis-url-rewrite-arr-issue)

Comment: having the same issue... uncheking "revererse rewrite host" didn't help...